# How can I read ArcServe6 backup tapes?

Tags: restore, novell, backup

I have got several 100 tapes of backups created with ArcServe6 for Netware. Also I have got two tape drives with which these tapes were written.

I tried setting up a Netware server and installing ArcServe6 on it, but ArcServe6 seems to be very particular on which tapes it likes and aborts at the first error it finds. That doesn't help me much. I don't care about errors, only about those tapes that are readable and those files that can be read without errors. (There are many duplicates to the chances are good that a file that cannot be read from one tape can be read from another.)

I seem to remember that there was other backup software that used the same format as ArcServe but it has been too many years ago to recall whether this is correct and if yes, which software it was.

Ideally I would prefer a Windows or Linux software to do this. Any hints?

Comment: I suspect your options are somewhere between "contact a data-recovery specialist" (IIRC there are some out there who specialise in getting data back from old tape formats) and "ouch". Sorry to be so negative but...

Comment: http://www.krollontrack.com/

Answer (score 2):

You may have some luck with ArcServe 6 for windows. Even back that far I believe the two products used the same tape format. Unfortunately I don't remember when the NW formats stopped being intelligible to the Windows product. I also remember one product using the same tape format, but all I remember is that it was NOT BackupExec.

Comment: Interestingly http://www.tecchannel.de/netzwerk/networkworld/praxis/403666/auf_nummer_sicher/index5.html says BackupExec 9.1 can read them (Article in German). I have yet to try it.